# ColorTranslator.ToHtml() return string issue

Tags: c#

I need the hexadecimal string of color so I am using `ColorTranslator.ToHtml()` property which returns string hex of Color.

If I choose a random color it returns "**#FFF0B6**" etc. However, if I choose a system-defined color for example `Color.Black` it returns "**Black**" in string.

I need hexadecimal color codes in string whether they are defined in system or not. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found this extension method worked well for me:

```
public static string ToHexValue(this Color color)
{
   return "#" + color.R.ToString("X2") + 
                color.G.ToString("X2") + 
                color.B.ToString("X2");
}
```

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.tohtml.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), that is indeed what `ColorTranslator.ToHtml()` is intended to do.

Comment: One strange issue I had with ColorTranslator.ToHtml(): For #00FF7F it returns "SpringGreen" (which is correct). But if I try to use that color-constant in a HTML5 canvas, it will simply be black. Other colors (like "Red") work correctly. Both Firefox and Edge (at least) show this strange behaviour. Sticking to the Hex representation might be a generally better idea.

Comment: You can also add the alpha channel to this method adding after the `B` line `+ color.A.ToString("X2")`

Answer (score 0):

This came from somewhere. It includes the Alpha value. You may not have noticed it:

```
    private string ColToArgb(Color c)
    {
        string A1 = System.Convert.ToString(IIf(c.A < 16, "0" + Hex(c.A), Hex(c.A)));
        string R1 = System.Convert.ToString(IIf(c.R < 16, "0" + Hex(c.R), Hex(c.R)));
        string G1 = System.Convert.ToString(IIf(c.G < 16, "0" + Hex(c.G), Hex(c.G)));
        string B1 = System.Convert.ToString(IIf(c.B < 16, "0" + Hex(c.B), Hex(c.B)));
        return "#" + A1 + R1 + G1 + B1;
    }
```